# Interior of sets within the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

So i know that if we have $Y \subset X$ with the subspace topology we know that the  $\overline{B}_Y$ = $Y \cap \overline{B}_X$ where the last terms denotes the closure in the different topologies.

Is there a familiar formula for the interior of a set $A$ in $Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not such formula.

By the relation between the interior and the closure, we have $\operatorname{int}_X(A) = X \setminus \overline{X \setminus A}^X$ and $\operatorname{int}_Y(A) = Y \setminus \overline{Y \setminus A}^Y = Y \setminus (Y ∩ \overline{Y \setminus A}^X) = Y \setminus \overline{Y \setminus A}^X$. Because of the inner $Y$, there is no way to relate the two interiors in a simple way.

In fact, we have always $\operatorname{int}_Y(Y) = Y$, but for every $Y$-open subset $U ⊆ Y$ we can change the topology on $X$ without changing the topology on $Y$ so that $\operatorname{int}_X(Y) = U$.

Comment: Alright , Thanks !!

Comment: A remark: you proved that $\operatorname{int}_Y(A) = \operatorname{int}_X(A\cup Y^c)\cap Y$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon You are right, I guess that counts as an admissible formula for OP. Strictly speaking, I just showed that there is no such formulat taking just $\operatorname{int}_X(Y)$ and postprocessing in $Y$.